# What happens to existing gems when I install RVM?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I currently have Ubuntu 10.04 Ruby 1.8 and Rails 2.3.8 with Apache2 and Phusion running on a machine where I've been developing this app.  During development I have installed many other gems as required for the app.  However I never had RVM installed from start.

Yesterday I tried to update rubygems from 1.3.5 to current version (because a gem wanted it) and because of ubuntu's specifics have completely mucked up my rubygems install.  The app runs but I can't get script/console to work.  The guys at rubygems.org suggested installing  a new version of ruby using RVM to get round the problem.

My questions are :

1. What happens to all the gems already installed on the system?
2. How does the new version affect/interact with my app?
3. Should I be uninstalling anything before installing RVM and a new ruby?
4. Why does this happen towards the END of a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gems installed on your system will still be installed on your system, but they won't be usable from your RVM ruby.  One of the main advantages of RVM is that you avoid nasty interactions with your system ruby.  It's not [recommended](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/), but you can optionally link or clone your system gems to an RVM environment if you really feel the need with

```
rvm gemdup system
```

Answer (score 0):

they stay around in the system location , but won't be used by RVM.